# Passing data from html server (with no php) to server with PHP and return data to that non-php server

Tags: php, javascript

Here's the deal:

I have blog, where I can only use a javascript and free php server. I need to send form data to that php server (this I know how to do), and **return some info back to the blog page**. Is that even possible?

Comment: Yes that is possible, using AJAX. Just output what you wish to get back, and interpret it. Use a library like jQuery to make life easier.

Comment: Beware of [CORS](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cross-origin_resource_sharing) issues then!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The only way I can think with out cross domain request is as below

1) make this form in your blog

```
<form action="FULL_URL_TO_YOUR_PHP_FILE">
 /// your fields
</form>
```

2) in your php file save data received from form and serialize the data(that you want to send back to your blog) in url format like

if you want to pass name and surname  YOUR_BLOG_URL?name=myName&surname=MySurname and make redirect from your php file to your blog

```
header('location:YOUR_BLOG_URL?name=myName&surname=MySurname');exit;
```

3) now on your blog make an onload event like if you have jquery than

```
$(document).ready(function(){
   alert(window.location.href);
   // do some spliting or regexp or anything else to get your data from url
})
```

Comment: Very thx! Now i can move on!